# detect hashchange and hash existed code run duplicate?

Tags: javascript, hash

I have the following code to detect hash changed and hash existed. The issue is that when people hitting the back button, the code will run twice because my url is www.site.com/#apple, the hash existed and computer think hash changed also. Do you anyway to run either one of them. It should be like that When people click my www.site.com, nothing happen. When people click one of the buttons, hashchange code run but the hash existed code will not run. When user go to my other page and hitting the back button, it run the hash existed code but not the hashchange code.

```js
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){ 
     alert('Apple');
});
if(window.location.hash) {
    alert('Apple');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear what you are trying to do from your description, but give this a try:

```
var hash = '';
$(document).load(function() {
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    if (hash == window.location.hash) {
        // do nothing, hash is the same as it was previously
        return;
    }

    hash = window.location.hash;

    if (hash) {
        alert("Apple");
    }
});
```